# Using custom view or UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I am thinking about just using an imageview or subclass an UIView and override the drawRect method. The View should look like this
[image]
Is it worth subclassing or should I just use an image?

At the end every row of the table contains a label and a textfield. It is the formular with required data for the registration progress.

The second question I have is, how can I disable the animation of the titleView of my NavigationControllers Navbar? It looks kind of strange if the titleView animates even if its the same image inside it.

Thanks for every adive.

Comment: why not just use a tableview and tableviewcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like some sort of table, so the best fit would be a grouped `UITableView`. To make the cells look like your image you can then set the `backgroundView` property to an `UIImageView` with a stretchable `UIImage`.

In general you should use a stretchable `UIImage` wherever possible instead of doing custom drawing. If you do drawing every view you draw will require its own backing store (4 bytes for every pixel), even if the drawn content is the same. Using the same image multiple times requires only the memory for this image once. And if you use a stretchable image you can save even more memory.

Custom drawing should only be used for things that cannot be created using images or for performance reasons in some special cases. Using this for a custom background always is wasteful.

Comment: My first thought was using a grouped UITable, but the cell should be static cells and when i tried this the storyboard said, i must have a tableviewcontrolelr for static cells.

Comment: Then just use a table view controller. There should be no problem using one.

Comment: There is one, if I add a UITableViewController I can't resize the tableview. It is always full screen, but i need a small one. So a UIViewController with a UITableView is the best, isn't it?